# How to insert "Checkboxes" values to SQL

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

well i'm confused on how to insert "Checkboxes" values to SQL
here's my code

```
$form['last'] = array(
'#type' => 'checkboxes',
'#title' => "Just title",
'#options' => array(
'opt1' => "Option 1",
'opt2' => "Option 2",
),
```

as you can see my form consist of two checkbox, so how to get the value and insert to sql language. anyone can give an example or hint

here the method that i'm used to get the value (i know its very wrong)

```
function fasil_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
  global $user;
  $entry = array(
  'uid'     => $user->uid,
  'test1'   => $form_state['values']['1first'],
  $jenis = 'aa_test';
  $return = insert_form($entry,$jenis);
}
```

ps : sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the value from the form or understanding how to insert it into the database? If it's the latter, can you show us what you have for an insert method right now?

Comment: well im having trouble understanding it. i have update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do but I think you're trying to insert a value in the database for each of the checkboxes ticked? If so this is the quickest way:

```
function fasil_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
  // Filter out un-checked items
  $checked = array_filter($form_state['values']['last']);

  global $user;
  foreach ($checked as $value) {
    $entry = array(
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'test1' => $value
    );
    $jenis = 'aa_test';
    insert_form($entry, $jenis);
  }
}
```

As already mentioned in another answer the simplest way to see what you need to get from the form is to output `$form_state['values']` in your submission function to see what was passed from the form.

However, rather than use the unsightly `print_r` and potentially messing up the form submission by calling `exit` prematurely (in Drupal 7 `drupal_exit()` should always be used instead of `exit` anyway), I strongly recommend you download and install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use it's `dpm()` function to print the variable to the screen.

Any variable passed to `dpm()` is outputted to the standard Drupal messages area, and becomes an easy to navigate on-screen hierarchy of that variable like this:

[image: Output of dpm() function]

You can use it absolutely anywhere in code within Drupal, e.g.

```
function fasil_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
  // Output the form submission array to the messages area:
  dpm($form_state['values']);
}
```

The Devel module is very good, and absolutely essential for any serious Drupal development.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way I like to look at my form output

```
function fasil_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
  header('content-type: Text/plain');
  print_r($form_state['values']);
  exit;

  global $user;
  $entry = array(
  'uid'     => $user->uid,
  'test1'   => $form_state['values']['1first'],
  $jenis = 'aa_test';
  $return = insert_form($entry,$jenis);
}
```

Now those 3 lines should make it clear how Drupal is submitting the data.

I believe you will need to loop through $form_state['values']['last'] and test that the key is not set to 0.

```
function fasil_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
  global $user;
  foreach ($form_state['values']['last'] as $key => $value) {
    if (value != 0) {
      // $form_state['values']['last'][$key] was checked
    }
    else {
      // $form_state['values']['last'][$key] not checked
    }
  }
}
```